# JQuery DataTable get row index after sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with data and a button that when clicked should do something with the row index. I've done this like so:

```
 $("#tblData tBody").on('click', '.updateButton', function() {

       updateButtonRowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length;
       alert(updateButtonRowIndex);
    });
```

This works but when I apply sorting to one of the columns, it no longer takes the actual row number but restarts from 0. This means that if I sort on ID and click on the button for 182 (now at the top) it will show that the row index is 0 and it will draw a value in the wrong row (the actual row 0).

Any solution for this?

Comment: If the row is at the top, its index _is_ 0. If your app logic can’t handle that and you need the original index - then loop through the rows one time before you sort, and store the current index into a custom property, so that you can access it from there later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value for the original row index, you can always use an attribute for that like this:

```
$("#tblData tBody").on('click', '.updateButton', function() {
  if ($(this).closest('tr').attr('originalRowIndex')) {
    alert("This is the original value: "
      $(this).closest('tr').attr('originalRowIndex'));
  } else {
    updateButtonRowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length;
    $(this).closest('tr').attr('originalRowIndex', updateButtonRowIndex)
    alert(updateButtonRowIndex);
  }
});
```